# Woocommerce Custom Coupon Dates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am a newbie in Woocommerce I just wanted to ask on how can I set the coupon to be enabled on certain booking dates? I already published the coupon code but I wanted that the coupon code can only be used in certain dates.

Jan 11, 2023 - Published coupon code, it can be only used on the dates of January, 20-29. I am using this method so that customers can use the code when they only selected the dates of January 20-29, 2023.

Answer (score -1):

> Jan 11, 2023 - Published coupon code, it can be only used on the dates of January, 20-29. I am using this method so that customers can use the code when they only selected the dates of January 20-29, 2023.

So the problem is solved? If not, you can try out 'WP Coupons and Deals – WordPress Coupon Plugin'. It is free and should fill your requirements. If the problem is solved, you can use the check mark on the left side of this post.

Comment: I'll try it first.